# PDOStatement::bindParam && PDOStatement::bindValue not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been reading a lot of posts here in StackOverFlow and the documentation info at php dot net.

Here's the code I'm tryng:

Example 1

```
$id = 1;
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = ?');
$sth->execute(array(intval($id)));
```

Example 2

```
$id = 1;
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Example 3

```
$id = 1;
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = :id');
$sth->bindValue(':id', intval($id));
$sth->execute();
```

If I try this:

```
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = 1');
$sth->execute();
```

I get the result I'm expecting but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

////////// EDIT 1

At the end of all of this examples I'm doing this:

```
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

The return is:

> Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

/////////// EDIT 2

Here's the code

```
class User {

    private $registry;
    private $userId;
    private $userLan;
    private $fullName;
    private $dob;
    private $email;
    private $sex;
    private $nationality;
    private $valid; // User valid?
    private $pdo; // PDO reference

    /**
     * Constructor del usuario. Se puede construir de dos formas, pasando email y password o pasando una id de usuario.
     * @param Registry $registry.
     * @param Int $id
     * @param String $email
     * @param String $password
     * @param String $username
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct ( Registry $registry, $id, $email, $password, $username)
    {
            echo "constructor user with id = $id ";
            $this->valid = false;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        if($id = 0 && $username != '' && $password != '')
        {
                    // ...
                    $this->valid = true;
        }
        //else if($id > 0)
            else
        {
            // $id = intval($id);
                echo "second if";
                $this->pdo = $registry->getObject('db')->getPdo();
                try
                {
                    $sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = :id');
                    $sth->execute(array(':id' => intval($id)));
                    //$sth->execute(array(intval($id)));
                    $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
                    print_r($arr);
                    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
                    print_r($result);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                echo "passing query";
                if($sth->rowCount() ==1)
                    echo "yeeeha";
                else
                    echo "not yeeha (".$sth->rowCount().") ";
                    // ...
                    $this->valid = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is going wrong at all?

Comment: Why you are doing $sth->errorInfo();? What for?

Comment: The problem is that the first 3 examples follows the right way to program this but no one is working. The last try (use the 1 in the sql) is working but it's not valid.

Comment: Just in case the query is wrong or if mysql is giving me any error.

Comment: @Jesus What is $this? Show us the whole program, so we could see, what's wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587

Comment: Though it's hardly believable that all these statements not working while the last one does

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah I don't know what is wrong here that is why im asking you :(

Comment: Don't ask me. A programmer should ask their code. Either there is an error (which have to be revealed) or the code works. As simple as that. Did you read the link I provided?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, thanks. I'm not catching any error I think that's just a query returning 0 rows..., $sth->rowCount() returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your error checking does not look correct:

```
$sth = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE ID_USR = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
```

This assumes that `PDO::prepare()` always returns an object, but that's not what [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) says:

> **Return Values**
>
> If the database server successfully prepares the statement,
>   PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. **If the database server
>   cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns
>   FALSE or emits PDOException** (depending on error handling).

I suggest you make your life easier and configure PDO to throw exceptions. This example is taken [from the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php):

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, actually fixed it (@YourCommonSense gave me another solution for this above) +1 /// Anyway the code is not throwing exceptions.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with "not working" as only explanation: any answer is just a blind shot.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to guess but the only sensible explanation I can find is a problem with $id and **lack of error reporting**